# Insert tab after some text instead of expanding when emmet expansion is on in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

In VS code, when `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` is on I can write something like "div", then press `[tab]` to generate a HTML tag like this:

`<div></div>`

Which is very useful, but it also happens when I press `[tab]` anywhere, If I write "something" and press `[tab]` I get this:

`<something></something>`

I would like to be able to create tags and ALSO be able to insert regular tabs (`\t`) after any word.

Is there a hotkey or something to insert a regular tab after some text without creating a tag?

Comment: press `Esc` when you see the Suggestion list

Comment: Oh, there is no suggestion list, when I press tab the text turns into a tag.

Comment: why do you have `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` set to true, When set to False Emmet will expand on Tab when you press a valid Emmet expression, and for known tags, otherwise try `somethingALT009` ALT is the key and keep it during typing `009` on numpad

Comment: oh, you are right, disabling `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` works, this setting is not self explanatory, it says "When enabled, Emmet abbreviations are expanded when pressing TAB", but if I disable it Emmet abbreviations are also expanded when pressing TAB, thank you so much for suggesting this, problem solved.

Comment: Maybe they have this setting for people that have Custom HTML Elements, maybe they should update the description for what the actual use case could be.